# The next Curzon number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question if someone can help i'll be so thankful for you.
I should write a program to find the next Curzon number, a given number N is said to be an Curzon Number
of

```
2^N + 1 is divisible by 2*N + 1.
```

Read in a number and find the next Curzon number!
i came up with this but its not working  i dont really know the next step

```
number = int(input("Write a number ")

num1 = 2** number +1 

num2 = 2* number +1 
 
if num1%num2==0:

    print() 
else: 

    print()
```

Test case examples:

```
input:
4

output:
5
```

explanation

```
check 5

2 ^ 5 + 1 = 33

2 * 5 + 1 = 11
```

33 is a multiple of 11 --> 5 is the next Curzon number!

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say ‘it’s not working’.

Comment: This particular code will throw a `SyntaxError` because there's a missing closing parenthesis here: `int(input("Write a number ")`

Comment: You are checking if the number you entered is a Curzon number. It is not. You need to increment number by 1 and check again. Do this in a loop until you find the Curzon number

Comment: I mean its not working with my method, also there is nothing related on the internet.

Comment: @Mymood Programming is not finding solutions on the Internet. It's a process where you make use of your basic understanding of the language to create something that solves the problem. It's like the difference between painting and paint-by-numbers.

Comment: For me your code works, in case the missing closing parenthesis is just an error when writing the code here

Comment: @Barmar I really understand you, because programming is based on logical thinking and the basics, first thing I tried and it didnt works so Google and did not find anything, I came to ask here because I am a beginner in programming Thank you anyway

Comment: You need to learn the basic concept of looping, this is critical to almost all programming.

Comment: @Barmar sure i will do, Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Azro's solution is smaller, but you should find this one easier to understand.

```
number = int(input("Write a number "))

while True:
    
    num1 = 2 ** number + 1
    num2 = 2 * number + 1
    
    if num1 % num2 == 0:
        print(number)
        break
    else:
        number += 1
```

I just took your code and put it in a loop, so I can increment `number` until the next Curzon number is found.

```
Write a number 4
5
```

Comment: thank you so much, yes indd, @Azro's solution is smaller, but your gives me another way to understand it

Comment: Np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple method to check if a vlaue is a curzon number

```
def is_curzon(value):
    return (2 ** value + 1) % (2 * value + 1) == 0
```

Then increment `number` until it is one

```
number = int(input("Write a number "))
while not is_curzon(number):
    number += 1
print(number, 'is the next curzon nb')
```

---

```
Write a number 123
125 is the next curzon nb
Write a number 126
134 is the next curzon nb
Write a number 135
138 is the next curzon nb
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, its works and sorry if my question looks like "Stupid question" this is my first experience with programming